# Problem with field not equal to null in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have `EXISTS` in huge query which looks like this:

```
EXISTS(
   SELECT 
      * 
   FROM 
      ExistTable
   WHERE
      ExTableFieldA = @SomeGuid AND
      ExTableFieldB = MainTableFieldB AND
      ExTableFieldA <> (
                         CASE
                           WHEN MainTableFieldZ = 10 THEN MainTableFieldYYY
                           ELSE NULL
                         END
                       )
)
```

The problem comes from `ELSE` part of `CASE` statement, this `ExTableFieldA <> NULL` will be always false. I could easily write another parameter @EmptyGuid and make it equal to `'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'` and everything will work but is this the best approach ?

Pretty much I want to execute another check into the exist for the small size of the records which return the "main" query.

Comment: `ExTableFieldA <> NULL` is not *false*, it's *unknown*. And because you got `and`ed conditions this results in *unknown* for every row, i.e. no row returned -> `exists` = false

Comment: yes, using `'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'` or just `''` or any other value that `ExTableFieldA` will never be is the right approach;  **no** value is **ever** equal *nor* unequal to `NULL` -- not even `NULL`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about removing the `case` and just using boolean logic?

```
WHERE ExTableFieldA = @SomeGuid AND
      ExTableFieldB = MainTableFieldB AND
      (MainTableFieldZ <> 10 OR ExTableFieldA <> MainTableFieldYYY)
```

I would also recommend that you *qualify* the column names by including the table alias.

Note:  This does assume that `MainTableFieldZ` is not `NULL`.  If that is a possibility than that logic can easily be incorporated.

Comment: Okay this works, but at least for me is a little bit trick to understand it on first look. Also from what I know the OR statement is really bad performance wise, because of that I choose case. I have indexs for both columns MainTableFieldZ  and ExTableFieldA and the OR will force the read of the whole table. So if the performance is really import, should I changed it to OR statements ?

Comment: @mybirthname . . . The performance may be fine  if you have an index on `(ExTableFieldB, ExTableFieldA)`.  `OR` is no worse than `CASE` from the performance perspective.

Comment: I think that's a good way to do it.  I don't like the concept of replacing NULL with values that never occur.  I can confess to writing things like COALESCE(surname, 'xxxxxxx') = SomeColumn

Comment: @Cato this was my main concern that I write parameter of value that never exist, which is stupid. I will mark it as correct, hope I don't have performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

`ELSE NULL` is implied even if you don't list it, but you could use `ISNULL` here.

```
ISNULL(ExTableFieldA,'') <> (
                         CASE
                           WHEN MainTableFieldZ = 10 THEN MainTableFieldYYY
                           ELSE ''
                         END
                       )
```

You may need to use some other value  like 9999 instead of `''`

Comment: ExTableFieldA is never null it is always a guid. I want to not execute the check ExTableFieldA <> of some guid for all the records of main query which does not have this MainTableFieldZ = 10. Because of that I check ExTableField <> null with the idea this will be always true(but obviously is not).

Comment: It will never = '' either though, which will always be true. So this doesn't work?